# How can I set a cookie's expiration in NodeJS?

Tags: cookies, node.js, setcookie

I'm writing my own cookies as part of a webserver I'm making using NodeJS (i.e. not using any packages). I've been able to do this just fine using something like:

```
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Set-Cookie':'sesh=wakadoo'
});
```

However, I'd like to make my cookies more persistent than they currently are (which is to say not at all). I've tried doing something like this:

```
var curdate = new Date();
response.writeHead(200, {
   'Set-Cookie':'sesh=wakadoo; expires='+curdate.toUTCString()
});
```

but alas this doesn't seem to work. chrome just ignores the expiration i set, and firefox never loads the page. My current goal is to simply give my cookie an expiration date that can be interpreted by the browser... does anybody know how to do this?

Best,
Sami

Comment: Have you tried [connect-cookieParser](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-cookieParser.html)

Comment: i'm specifically trying to do this without a package. if i were to use a package, it would be cookie-node

Comment: I'm applying you should be using express or connect anyway. So just use `cookieParser`

Comment: why would i use a package full of various features for an app that only needed one of said features? if i wanted to use a package, i would have used one that was made specifically for that feature (something that exists). and either way, the point of this post is to learn how to do this without a package - i want to learn more about the inner workings of nodeJS.

Comment: if you like re-inventing wheels and doing everything the hard way then go for it o/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try giving the expires some lead time, like an day. The client/server may not read it because it's expired when you submit it.

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie':'sesh=wakadoo; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+86409000).toUTCString()
});
```

Comment: perfect that worked! that's probably a bug that mozilla should fix though... a page shouldn't hang up because a cookie expires during the same day... chrome just treats that as if it were a non-persistent cookie.

Comment: It hangs? That's a bit odd. I write a quick test for that.

Comment: if implementing, remove the semi-colon at the end of the JSON .toUTCString(); - no punctuation necessary

Comment: @eugene Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: `+new Date(new Date().getTime()+86409000).toUTCString()` returns NaN.
Should be without **+**